# How to add padding for column google-charts

Tags: google-visualization

I'm use column google-chart with annotations. For annotation set option `alwaysOutside: true`. But I have one problem.

[image]

My annotation label automaticly shifting down for column with max value.

How I can fix this behavior?

My chart options here:

```
const chartOptions = {
  legend: 'none',
  width: 750,
  height: 285,
  bar: { groupWidth: '95%' },
  fontName: 'Open Sans',
  fontSize: 14,
  enableInteractivity: false,
  colors: ['#FF2D55', '#4772D1'],
  vAxis: {
    format: '0',
    baseline: 0,
    viewWindowMode: 'pretty',
    viewWindow: {
      min: 0
    }
  },
  annotations: {
    alwaysOutside: true,
    style: 'point',
    stem: {
      length: 5,
      color: '#FFFFFF'
    },
    textStyle: {
      fontName: 'Open Sans',
      fontSize: 16,
      bold: true,
      color: 'black',
      opacity: 1
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'none'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. Maybe someone needs.

After I got the data for my chart, I found max value in series and set option `vAxis.minValue` dynamically. 
Code example:

```
const maxValue = this.getMaxValueInSeries(chartSeries);
this.chartOptions.vAxis.minValue = maxValue + 1;
```

It's work for me. Enjoy.